# Conventional notation for samples of random variables?

Tags: probability, statistics, notation

Is there any conventional notation to separate population values from sample values in statistics?

For example, how would one differentiate $\mathbb{E}(X) = \mu$, the population mean, from $\mathbb{E}(X) = \bar{x}$, the sample mean? Would you use a small $x$ like this: $\mathbb{E}(x) = \bar{x}$ ?

Comment: I have only ever seen $\Bbb E$ used when talking about the population mean. For the sample mean, I think it's fairly common to write $\hat \mu$, and similarily, $\hat\sigma$ for the sample standard deviation, but I don't have any hard sources to back it up right now.

Comment: $\bar{X}$ is usually not seen as an expected value. Also, are you considering the case in which $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables with $E[X_1]=\mu$?

Comment: I'm considering the case where I just have a sample to work with (no population mean, no probability distribution) so writing $\mathbb{E}(X)$ feels wrong. My question also extends to $\mathrm{Var}(X)$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\v}{\operatorname{var}}\newcommand{\e}{\operatorname{E}}$Some aspects of notation in this regard are chaotic, but nobody uses such a notation as $\e(X)$ to denote a sample mean.

If the sample is $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ and these are i.i.d. random variables then $\e(X_1)=\cdots=\e(X_n)$ is the population mean, and the sample mean $(X_1+\cdots+X_n)/n$ is often denoted $\overline X$ or $\overline X_n,$ and that is random variable in its own right, having the same expected value as it any of the observations in the sample, i.e. $\e(\overline X) = \e(X_1).$

Very often Greek letters are used, thus: $\mu=\e(X_1) = \cdots =\e(X_n),$ $\sigma^2 = \v(X_1) = \cdots = \v(X_n).$

Then we have
\begin{align}
\mu & = \e(X_1) = \cdots = \e(X_n) = \text{the population mean} \\[10pt]
\sigma^2 & = \v(X_1) = \cdots = \v(X_n) = \text{the population variance} \\[10pt]
\overline X & = \frac{X_1+\cdots+X_n} n = \text{the sample mean} \\[10pt]
S^2 & = \frac { (X_1-\overline X)^2 + \cdots + (X_n - \overline X)^2} {n-1} = \text{the sample variance}
\end{align}
And $S^2$ is also a random variable in its own right.

One also often writes $\widehat \mu$ or $\widehat{\sigma^2}$ to refer to functions of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ used as estimators of the unobservable population mean and population variance. These are also random variables in their own right.

In this context, the word "random" often in effect means depending on the sample.

Comment: I see. So if $s^2$ is the sample variance, what would I use for sample covariance, and correlation?

Comment: @seven11 : First, you'll notice that I used a capital $S$ above, i.e. $S^2,$ not $s^2.$ Another convention is that (capital) $S^2$ is a random variable, with a probability distribution, and (lower-case) $s^2$ is its observed value for the particular sample.

Comment: Sometimes $r$ or $R$ is used for a sample correlation and $\rho$ (not to be confused with $p$) for the population correlation.